# Deserialize the Json Object C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I want to deserialize the below Json object,

```
var jsonObject = {
    "name": "sections",
    "record": [
        { 
            "id": 1,
            "name": "sections",
            "tables": 
            {
                "sections": 
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In C#

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonObject);
```

Added below classes for deserialize

```
public class Response
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name;

            [JsonProperty("record")]
            public List<Records> Record;
        }

        public class Records
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public int Id;

            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name;

            [JsonProperty("tables")]
            public List<Table> Tables;

        }

        public class Table
        {
            [JsonProperty("sections")]
            public List<Sections> Sections;
        }

        public class Sections
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string id;

            [JsonProperty("type")]
            public string Type;

        }
```

I want to get the "Type" from the json, but it is not deserialized properly. Can anyone suggest how to get the Type from the Json Object.

Comment: Unsure if it's just a typo, but you're missing a double-quote before `type` in your JSON.

Comment: Take a look at JsonSchema.Parse().
The similar question was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906220/deserialize-json-in-a-tryparse-way

Answer (score 1):

From the question, the class doesn't match.

```
public class Response
        {
            public string Name;
            public List<Records> Record;
        }

        public class Records
        {
            public int Id;
            public string Name;
            public List<Table> Tables;
        }

        public class Table
        {
            public List<Sections> Sections;
        }

        public class Sections
        {
            public string id;
            public string Type;

        }
```

Sections doen't have [ ], neither does tables, so they are not lists.

I'd also change you deserialization code to this

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonObject, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                });
```

So that you aren't annotating every class property just for camel cased JSON.

Comment: tried what?  fixing the json or changing your model?

Comment: solution which you mentioned

Comment: so you changed the json to this?
var jsonObject = {
    "name": "sections",
    "record": [
        { 
            "id": 1,
            "name": "sections",
            "tables":  [
            {
                "sections":  [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "2"
                }
    ]
            }
   ]
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize the object since the property `type` is not correctly formatted.
Instead of

```
type ": "
                    2 "
```

you must set `type` as follow

```
"type":"2"
```