# How to know if json can convert to a given type

Tags: c#, json

The json `token.ToObject<T>` method can throw if json is not able to convert the data in token the to the type `T`.

I would like to do a early test and need a method like this:

```
bool JsonConvert.CanConvert<TSrc, TDest>();
```

I don't find any reference to something close to it.

**[Precision]**

Actually `TSrc` here is not composed but a basic type.

**[Edit]**

When I say that I want to do an early test, I talk about a test done **before** any attempt to parse somethings.

Actually I don't have any json file around when I need to do the test.

So the [TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906220/deserialize-json-in-a-tryparse-way) or the [TryCatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40846833/361177) pattern doesn't match my need.

Comment: There's only one way to know if it will parse to a given type: parse it.

Comment: That likely doesn't exist because the idea is that if the json isn't what you expect then you're in an exceptional or error case.

Answer (score 3):

Why an early test?
Just enclose the call with a try-catch. What you're suggesting would internally parse the string as well, so speed-wise it would make no difference. Better yet, it will be parsed only once. If it succeeds, fine. If not, you'll know too.

Comment: `Why an early test?`... because I actually need it ... I want my generic code to throw on construction, not in parsing.

Comment: "What you're suggesting would internally parse the string as well, so speed-wise it would make no difference."  You can't actually know if it will parse into a structure unless you attempt it.  There is no shortcut.